# Value of $ \sum \limits_{k=1}^{81} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{80} + \sqrt{81}} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried my best, but I am totally clueless about it. Worse thing is we were supposed to arrive at the answer in approximately $ 2 $ minutes. The correct answer is $ 8 $, right? Can you kindly explain how to arrive at it? I hope it won’t be too much bother. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the question right? If the terms were multiplied, it would be easy.

Comment: @JanDvorak Sorry for the delay in replying to you.Yes, I have got the question right.I double-check things before putting them up on this reputed maths forum.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Note that

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}} = \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} $$

Then you have a telescoping sum

Comment: Thanks Muzzlator for your fine answer.

Answer (score 11):

As \begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i+1}} = \frac{\sqrt{i}-\sqrt{i+1}}{\sqrt{i}-\sqrt{i+1}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i+1}} = \frac{\sqrt{i}-\sqrt{i+1}}{-1} = {\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}}
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{80} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i+1}} = \sum_{i=1}^{80} {\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}} = \sqrt{80+1} -\sqrt{1} = 8
\end{align}

Comment: A prof of mine always said, that "text is the shortest connection between two formulas" ;)

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1} }{(2-1)} +\ldots +\frac{\sqrt{81} - \sqrt{80} }{(81-80)}=\sqrt{81}-\sqrt{1}=9-1=8 $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jim.