# Simplify $\frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{4}} + \cdots+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{24} + \sqrt{25}}$

Tags: generating-functions

Simplify$$\frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{4}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{24} + \sqrt{25}}.$$

I know you can solve this using generating functions but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: Almost the same: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310962/value-of-sum-limits-k-181-dfrac1-sqrtk-sqrtk1-dfrac1

Answer (score 19):

**Hint:** Multiply top and bottom of $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}$ by $\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$, and watch the house of cards collapse.

Comment: House of cards. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Here, we simply use André Nicolas' hint to observe the "collapsing house of cards":
We first represent the $k$th term of the sum, to simplify matters.

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{24} \color{blue}{\bf \frac{1}{\sqrt k + \sqrt{k+1}}}\quad = \quad\frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{4}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{24} + \sqrt{25}}$$

$$ {\bf NOTE:}\quad \frac{1}{\sqrt k + \sqrt{k+1}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt k - \sqrt{k+1}}{\sqrt k - \sqrt{k+1}} =  \frac{\sqrt k - \sqrt{k+1}}{k - (k + 1)} = \color{blue}{\bf \sqrt {k+1} - \sqrt{k}}$$
$$ $$
$$
\begin{align}\sum_{k = 1}^{24} \frac{1}{\sqrt k + \sqrt{k+1}} \quad
& = \quad\sum_{k=1}^{24} \sqrt {k+1} - \sqrt{k} \\ \\
& = (\sqrt 2 - 1) + (\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2) + (\sqrt 4 - \sqrt 3) \cdots + (\sqrt{25} -\sqrt {24}) \\ \\
& = \sqrt{25} - 1= 4 \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What does this add to the other answer?

Comment: @Did I know you live in a rather lofty realm, so perhaps you forget not everyone has your level of "acuity" or "brilliance". Some people are actually just learning about these sorts of sums/series...

Comment: I do not know how you know that. Anyway, even if this answer is a tad too rhetorical for my taste, thanks for it. If I get your point correctly, you are saying that you added this answer for the readers who failed to get the argument in André's answer. Maybe these exist.